# UbuntuOne doesn't sync on my computer

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, macbook

File sync has stopped working on my computer.  When I open UbuntuOne I see the following error:  `File Sync error. (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "current_status" with signature " on interface "com.ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Status" doesn't exist)`.  When I click "Reset" nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug and is reported in launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/858808), please go to this bug and click "this bug affects me" and you'll get notified when it's fixed. There's also a workaround noted in the bug.

Very sorry for the inconvenience.